# functions used to encrypt password in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, passwords

I am programming a PHP site that allows users to register,I'm using codeigniter php and I want to know the best function to encrypt passwords
and what difference between this function?

Comment: Use the md5() function to encrypt password you can use $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[passconf]|md5'); in codeigniter

Comment: To improve @Arunkumar's comment: DON'T use md5 to encrypt passwords.

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert Why you say DON'T use md5 to encrypt passwords ?

Comment: @Arunkumar — It's broken.

Comment: @Arunkumar: MD5 is not collision resistant.

Comment: @Arunkumar Probably because without a proper salt, it is far too easy to de-hash an md5 password.

Comment: Because md5 is weak algorithm. Use sha256. Use salt of course.

Comment: See [the password hashing faq](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) — and hash passwords, don't encrypt them.

Comment: @Arunkumar There are numerous discussions in stackoverflow, but you should simply trust PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passwords should almost never be encrypted. Instead, they should be one-way hashed.

Generally, [bcrypt is recommended](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/), as it's resistant to brute forcing, where common alternatives like `md5` or `sha1` fail.

Comment: Hadn't encountered bcrypt before. Sounds like I need to update my hashing techniques..

Answer (score 2):

Use PHPass: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

> The preferred (most secure) hashing method supported by phpass is the OpenBSD-style Blowfish-based bcrypt, also supported with our public domain crypt_blowfish package (for C applications), and known in PHP as CRYPT_BLOWFISH, with a fallback to BSDI-style extended DES-based hashes, known in PHP as CRYPT_EXT_DES, and a last resort fallback to MD5-based salted and variable iteration count password hashes implemented in phpass itself (also referred to as portable hashes).

Put it in `application/third_party`, and use vanilla PHP to load it (not CI's loader):

```
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php';
$hash_iterations = 100;
$portable_hashes = FALSE;
$phpass = new PasswordHash($hash_iterations, $portable_hashes);
```

Example usage:

```
// Hash a password before storing it in the DB
$hashed_password = $phpass->HashPassword($user_input);

// Check a given password against a stored hashed password
$is_valid = $phpass->CheckPassword($user_input, $stored_hash_of_password);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom encryption class which im using in codeigniter

```
<?php
class Encryption {
    var $skey   = "EsUriEncKey2012"; 

    public  function safe_b64encode($string) {

        $data = base64_encode($string);
        $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function safe_b64decode($string) {
        $data = str_replace(array('-','_'),array('+','/'),$string);
        $mod4 = strlen($data) % 4;
        if ($mod4) {
            $data .= substr('====', $mod4);
        }
        return base64_decode($data);
    }

    public  function encode($value){ 

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $text = $value;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($this->safe_b64encode($crypttext)); 
    }

    public function decode($value){

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $crypttext = $this->safe_b64decode($value); 
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($decrypttext);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't go rolling your own crypto.

Comment: He's using PHP's mcrypt so he's not rolling his own crypto, just building a wrapper around AES (Rijndael_256). Even still you should be hashing passwords with a salt, not using a bidirectional algorithm.

Comment: This is a terrible way to store passwords. **DO NOT USE IT.**